# Are there any usable path-finding libraries for python?

Tags: python, c, performance, path-finding

I'm working on a real-time isometric RPG in python, and wish to target mobile devices as a platform. The main area where I'm having difficulties is with my pathfinding. I have tried a few algorithms including A* and a few tweaks to better fit the maps I'm using.

I am satisfied with the results of my algorithm - they give the illusion of some intelligence while being deterministic, and being consistent in either direction so that two characters targeting each others' locations will collide in the middle.

My problem is that while the results look good on the PC where I have all the processing power I could ask for, on my mobile it's quite another story, and there is often a second or more delay while the algorithm is calculated. For this reason I am considering writing a library for this with the most performance-intensive code written in C, however if there is an existing solution for this, or a better way I could do this, I would be all ears.

I stumbled across [python-pathfinding](http://code.google.com/p/python-pathfinding/) but this seems to be slower than what I have built myself for my use case.

---

### My use case:

My maps are build from levels, which are surrounded by walls (visible or invisible), and must be linked by doors (visible or invisible).

My current approach is to have two different algorithms:

- Within a room I search individual tiles as nodes, with each boundary as an equal-cost edge, using a depth-first in the direction of the target location
- Between rooms where each door is a node. The shortest possible path through a room (from door to door) is calculated using the first algorithm and stored in a hash table as the edge cost between those nodes. Sets of edges that can be traversed to get from one node to another are then calculated and also stored in the hash table, and it is not permitted to include the same edge more than once in the same path.

I spawn a separate process on start-up that generates a graph for the second algorithm using the first, and this solves many of my issues, rooms tend to be relatively small and so the penalty of on-the-fly path-finding is kept lower than it otherwise could be, and then for longer distances:

- the first algorithm is used to calculate the distance from the current location to every door in the current room.
- the first algorithm is used to calculate the distance from each door in the target room to the target location.
- the output of the second algorithm is used to get the set of paths between rooms
- the cost of these is added to the cost of getting to the first door and from the last door
- the set of solutions is sorted by cost in such a way that the order of paths of the same cost will always be consistent
- the first item in the set of solutions is chosen.

Comment: How are you targeting mobile devices with Python? I know there's a Python runtime for Android, but I thought it was still pretty rough around the edges, and I don't know of any way to run Python on iOS.  Just curious.

Comment: The main platform I've been targeting is Maemo/Meego which supports it natively, however you can produce self-contained distributable packages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, I know a quite efficient and generic library to handle A* search algorithm. It is [lib2dp](http://lib2dp.sourceforge.net/). You may easily plug your python-generated graph into this library and get a quick answer.

Second, A* is essentially good to find an optimal path according that:

- You have perfect and total information about your surrounding.
- Your surrounding is considered as 'static'.

If you break one of these rules you may want to consider an alternative algorithm called '[D*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D*)'.

Of course, this has a huge cost in term of performance. So, it's up to you to find the best trade-off for your program.

Answer (score 4):

If you can reduce your game environment into a graph, then http://networkx.lanl.gov/ has lots of good built in algorithms for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2):

If you already have a python version you're happy with, then why not run it through [py2cmod](http://sourceforge.net/projects/py2cmod/)? That should get you most of the way to a c version of your current algorithm.

Another alternative is [psyco](http://psyco.sourceforge.net/introduction.html), though it has a high overhead.

Comment: how good is that at optimising algorithms and data structures? There's probably a lot of overhead in python's new style classes etc which I don't need in c, and probably a fair few bits which can be done efficiently with pointer arithmetic. I don't believe psyco supports all version of python, which would mean that's out for me currently. I'll have to take a look at the results.

Comment: I'm not sure myself, but python has good integration with c. My thinking was to do this as transparently as possible. Like with c and assembly. Instead of rewriting the whole thing, transform it to get a base version, and go from there. I doubt you'll find a solution that does not require either rewriting in a different language, or refactoring to use a different library, which is almost the same thing.

Comment: yeah I guess you're right. If noone can siggest a decent library premade, I may as well give that a try. I'd just prefer something that's already somewhat mature, as then I don't have to spend so much time debugging etc, and can concentrate on the rest of the project.

Comment: That's always preferable, but not always available. Whatever you come up with, you should look into documenting it for the rest of the python community. I wouldn't be surprised if other people have the same issue. That is, a working python program that needs a set of functions converted to c for speed.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out [libtcod](http://doryen.eptalys.net/libtcod/) and the `libtcodpy` Python wrapper. Personally, though, I don't quite like how the wrapper isn't very Pythonic, being an unnecessarily monolithic script with excessive usage of function name prefixes (at least, the last time I used it). I refactored the wrapper at one point and fixed it up for Python 3, but that was a year ago and so things may have changed since then.